# Handling Multiple Interviews

Tags: job-search, job

Recently, I applied for two positions at one university. I received a quick reply for a video interview and immediately thereafter the campus visit. Right after my campus visit, I got a call back on the second application. After much deliberation, I recinded the application for the second position interview. Is this appropriate? Is there etiquette for applying to one or two positions at the same institution?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody would fault you for pursuing any promising job offer, even if two are at the same place. (If they're petty enough to be upset with you for this then you wouldn't want to work there anyway.) If you've already rescinded the application they're not going to be upset with you for that either. These are regular problems faced by departments doing job searches.

Some institutions might have an internal arbitration process that would have to happen if both departments want to make an offer. This is to avoid a situation where you try to use offers from both departments as leverage for better compensation or a startup package.

Comment: Thank you, David. This makes sense. It just seemed awkward.

Answer (score 1):

In academia, it is common for candidates - especially for faculty positions (which you don't mention if these positions are faculty or administrative ones) - to apply for multiple jobs. During a single job market season, some candidates may apply for dozens of positions. Often, they are at different institutions, but there are cases where people apply to multiple positions at the same institution. You already rescinded the other position, so there is not much you can do at this point. However, it is often wise to make sure that you have an offer of employment "in hand" before fully rescinding other applications. If you were a strong candidate for both positions, you could always let the search chair or administrator know that you are being considered for another position. When I was a faculty search chair, candidates were often frank about having other interviews or even offers. It is expected - at least in my field (social and health sciences). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Nicole.I just wasn't sure about how to communicate the issue with the first committee. Your reply has helped.